Backpack laravel ediitable_select options
In my table status column values are 'Completed', 'In Progress', 'Scheduled', 'Canceled', but in my AdminCrudController user is only allowed to update the status 'Cancel' and 'Completed'
How to add drop down options as 'Cancel' and 'Completed' with the current status by default
$this->crud->addColumn(
            [
                'name'    => 'status',
                'label'   => 'Status',
                'type'    => 'editable_select',
                'options' => [
                    'Completed'=>'Completed',
                    'In Progress'=>'In Progress',
                    'Scheduled'=>'Scheduled',
                    'Canceled'=>'Canceled'

                ],
            ]
        );

